# Thermodynamics for 1D line of 3D dipoles

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

The 1D Ising model was solved almost a century ago. This model assumed spins that point along the 1D line to the left or right and only considered nearest neighbors, so that the Hamiltonian with no external field is

$$H = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} -J \sigma_i \sigma_{i+1}$$

Consider the full dipole potential
$$U = \frac{1}{r^3} \left( \mathbf{\mu}_1 \cdot \mathbf{\mu}_2 -\frac{3}{r^2}(\mathbf{\mu}_1 \cdot \mathbf{r})(\mathbf{\mu}_2 \cdot \mathbf{r}) \right)$$

leading to the classical Hamiltonian

$$H = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{N} \frac{1}{(i-j)^3} \left( \mathbf{\mu}_i \cdot \mathbf{\mu}_j -3 \mu_{i}^{(x)}\mu_{j}^{(x)} \right) $$

i.e., the dipoles can take any orientation. Has the 1D case for this potential been solved for nearest neighbor interactions ($j=i+1$)? And if non-nearest neighbor interactions are included, does that change Landau's finding that there are no phase transitions in 1D?

Comment: I don't know whether explicit expressions can be obtained, but I doubt it. Nevertheless, as long as the interaction decays faster than $1/(i-j)^2$, there will be no phase transition. Indeed, there is a very general theorem that tells you the following: if the maximal interaction energy between an interval of length $n$ and the rest of the line is bounded uniformly in $n$ (which is the case if the interaction decays fast enough), then there is a unique infinite-volume Gibbs measure.